# get column value according to another column value from datatable in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

i have a datatable similar to this:

id msg
1  thank you..
2  kindly...
3  please insert..
4  please stop

i need to get a msg according to a specific id from the datatable that's how i'm filling my datatable:

```
msgTable = selectMsg()
MsgBox(i need to get the msg here)

   Public Function selectMsg() As DataTable
    Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("selectMsg", cn)
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
    'If dt.Rows.Count <> 0 Then
    '    dt.Rows.Clear()
    'End If
    Try
        da.Fill(msgDS, "N_AI_HOME_CARE")
        msgDT = msgDS.Tables(0)
    Catch ex As Exception
        logFile("SP selectMsg ---" + ex.Message)
    End Try
    Return msgDT
End Function
```

any suggestion will be much appreciated !

Comment: Do you really need a stored procedure to simply return a single string from your table?

Comment: well yes actually i do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that your stored procedure returns the whole datatable of your messages (a very bad move because if the table is big you could have performance and network problems) then you need to apply the [Select method with a filter expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx) to your returned datatable

```
msgTable = selectMsg()
Dim rows() = msgTable.Select("ID = " & idOfMessage)
if rows.Length > 0 then
    MsgBox(row(0)(1).ToString()) ' read the first row, second column of the table'
End If
```

But I think you should use a more correct approach using a simple ExecuteScalar that doesn't return the entire datatable but just the first row and first column of a query

```
Public Function selectMsg(idOfMessage as Integer) As String
    Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT msg from tableName where ID = @id", cn)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", idOfMessage)
    Dim result = command.ExecuteScalar()
    if string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) Then
        result = "No message found"
    End If
    return result
End Function
```

Comment: well i need to use a stored procedure not an executeScalar but the select method did not work... :(

Answer (score 0):

well acctually i just found that you use

```
MsgBox(msgTable.Rows(0)(1).ToString())
```

without any select method :)

Comment: But that's true only if your stored procedure returns just one record. If you have more than one row then you need the Select.

Comment: no dear... i can use Rows(0)(1) or Rows(1)(1) or Rows(2)(1) etc...depending on which row i need :)